# a second course in abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I recently read an abstract algebra textbook, "A first course in abstract algebra" by John Fraleigh. I am interested in continuing to do some more self studying. What is a good book for a second course in the subject for self studying?
Thanks.

Comment: What was covered in the text?

Comment: A (perhaps) lesser known gem is Paolo Aluffi's "Algebra: Chapter 0". It is phenomenally written, with exceptional clarity and a great sense of humor. The exercises are exceptional and instructive, and the organization is especially great. He dives right in with a bit of category theory at the beginning, which provides a really cohesive vision of algebraic structures that I think can be lacking in other texts. Can't recommend it enough.

Comment: @AWertheim: Is that the text that groups its material according to general concepts (homomorphisms, quotients, etc) rather than types of abstract structure (group, ring, etc)?

Comment: @StrangerLoop: indeed. I think it really helps provide a deeper understanding of the principles at play in a lot of algebraic constructs. Of course, I'm not trying to present my knowledge as anything more than it is - I'm an algebra neophyte in the grand scheme of things. Still, it's done a lot for my understanding, at least.

Comment: @AWertheim, oooh.  My interest is piqued.  I'll have to find that one once I'm back on campus.

Comment: @Kyle Gannon: The text goes from groups to extension fields (algebraic closure...) to automorphisms of fields and galois theory.

Answer (score 1):

I used Fraleigh in the first course in algebra I ever took. Then I used Hungerford's *Algebra* for several additional courses (as a student). I think Hungerford is the best abstract algebra text I have ever seen. I strongly recommend it. It's in Springer's GTM (Graduate Texts in Mathematics) series.

**Addendum:** But Hungerford is no slim text. It's a honkin' bible.

Answer (score 1):

Michael Artin's Algebra is a great choice.  It is pretty advanced for an undergrad book, but very well-written, and at times even humorous or entertaining.  It's amazing that Artin manages to discuss so much material in this slim book--he even reviews some abstract linear algebra. It has an introduction to Galois theory at the end.

You can also check out the classic texts by Herstein and Jacobson (the latter is usually used by first-year grad students).

Comment: My book studied field extensions, etc, and ended with galois theory. Would you still suggest Michael Artin's book? By the way  thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with StrangerLoop's response. I learned what I know about Galois theory from Artin's Algebra, and it had a reasonable amount of depth while being understandable at the same time.

Now that I've actually completed two semesters of undergrad abstract algebra, I've found Dummit and Foote to be a rather approachable text as well.  I can see how certain sections of Dummit and Foote can be too advanced for the first time through, but it's been very pleasant going back and adding depth to material I've previously been introduced to.

Comment: I've spent a good amount of time studying from Dummit and Foote. It's an excellent text in its own right, and has a ton of material for the voracious algebravore. That being said, much like Hungerford, it's a bit dry and the sheer amount of material can be overwhelming. It also proceeds in the traditional groups, rings, fields presentation of things, which is fine for a first course, but I think a second course might benefit from a stronger category theoretic emphasis throughout.